# Nginx: wild card dns redirect URL to subdomain

Tags: nginx, web-server, redirect, regex

I'm trying to redirect the following URL

```
Http://example.com/category/something
```

To redirect to

```
Http://something.example.com/category/something
```

Where "something" could be anything.

I've already set up nginx and Dns for wild card and confirmed that that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is an orthodox way:

```
location /category/ {
      location ~ ^/category/(?<category>.+)$ {
            return 302 http://$category.example.com/category/$category
      }
}
```

Without "rewrite". 
Tested at nginx/1.0.0

Comment: This worked great.

Answer (score 1):

untested.. but should work

```
location / {
   rewrite  ^/category/(.*)$  http://$1.example.com/category/$1  permanent;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work - does the file or path have to exist or does nginx just route it as requested?