# How to Nginx rewrite domain.com/some1/some2 to some2.domain.com/some1

Tags: nginx

I've read some very old answers to similar problems in nginx. But the 'chosen solution' in that answer didn't solve my problem. One such stack answer I tried is `[in the link given]`.

I hope the query given in the question is clear enough.

[link](https://serverfault.com/q/328380/541996)

Comment: It is also already the answer. There is no point in copy&pasting it into the same answer again. Provide what you tried and we can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: I got busy in some other project, thank you for the encouragement to go with earlier answer only. I'll report back, albeit very late.